# Calculating Covariance Matrix of Two Distributions In Python

Tags: python, statistics, standard-deviation, deviation

I would like to calculate the Covariance matrix of two distributions, what could be the possible ways to calculate them in python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [numpy](https://numpy.org/).

```
>>> from numpy import cov
>>> cov([1, 2, 3], [2, 12, 14])
array([[  1.        ,   6.        ],
       [  6.        ,  41.33333333]])
```